# selenium checkbox doesn't work on python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to test if a checkbox is checked.

How can I check the state of a checkbox using `selenium` Python3?

```
driver.find_element_by_id('privacyCheck1').is_selected()
driver.find_element_by_id('privacyCheck1').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='privacyCheck1']").click()


  <div class="mail_privacy_check">
    <p class="comment">
      <input type="checkbox" id="privacyCheck1" class="privacyCheck">
      <label for="privacyCheck1">...</label>
    </p>
    <div class="tableware typecolor">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean doesn't work?? need to share if there is any exception as well

Comment: and try once as `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label[for = 'privacyCheck1']").click()` and let me know..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur What I mean is...can't detect checkbox...which means failed.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur also I'm afraid that your code does not help me...It detect label not checkbox...

Comment: Yes I know it's detect label element instead, but some case label supports click event to select checkbox due to designing issue that's why I suggested you

Comment: No problem if it's not working. But could you let me know if there is any exception when you select checkbox ??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur There is no exceptions. It passed. but actually it is not. because It doesn't checked checkbox. I didn't make try-catch statement yet.

Comment: Ok try using then `execute_script()` as `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", driver.find_element_by_id('privacyCheck1'))` and let me know..:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur It works~! You are the best!!
In this case, I have to using the script. I didn't know that :)

Comment: Ok, I have provided it as an answer with the explanation, you can see it and let me know if you have any problem. Also make it as [correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if this answer is helped. Thanks

Comment: Please don;t post pictures of your code. Past the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time due to designing issues or other unknown issue `WebElement::click()` does not work as expected.

So in this case selenium also has provided to perform certain action silently using `JavaScript` code to get rid from the issue.

For this purpose there is a method name [`execute_script()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) where you can call directly JavaScript code on current window frame/iframe for solving your purpose. In this method first parameter input is the piece of JavaScript code and second parameter is the array of the object which can be use in the JavaScript code as JavaScript variable. In the JavaScript code this array of the object input takes in `arguments` variable.

So you can perform click as below :-

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", driver.find_element_by_id('privacyCheck1'))
```

**Note** :- The JavaScript injection `HTMLElement.click()` shouldn't be used in a testing context. It defeats the purpose of the test. First because it doesn't generate all the events like a real `click (focus, blur, mousedown, mouseup...)` and second because it doesn't guarantee that a real user can interact with the element. But to get rid from the issue you can use it as an alternate solution.